# Dividing two or more rows in single attribute table?

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, qgis-3, fields-attributes

I want to divide rows in my attribute table. I need to divide the lengths of rows having specific IDs. For instance the length of ID 21 divided by the length of ID 11. An this calculation execute for all rows in the table This can be easily solve with the field calculator. But what if I want to keep dividing all the rows (e.g. id 22/12, 23/13, 24/14, etc...)

Is there a way to automatically do this calculation for all rows?

[image]

Comment: I wan to divide the lengths of rows having specific IDs. For instance the length of ID 21 divided by the length of ID 11. An this calculation execute for all rows in the table

Comment: There is more than one way to "divide" a row -- please [Edit] the question to clarify your meaning by providing a complete example of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Always 10 ID units apart?

Comment: Yes, IDs are always 10 units apart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store ID and length in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with ID as key and length as value. Then supply current ID-10 to the dictionary and get length. For some IDs there will not be a ID-10, those will get value 999 (or whatever you want).

```py
idfield = 'ID' #Change ID to match the name of your id field
oldlengthfield = 'Shape_Leng' #Change name
newlengthfield = 'newLength' #Change name

layer = iface.activeLayer()
d = {feature[idfield]:feature[oldlengthfield] for feature in layer.getFeatures()} #Store IDs and lengths in a dictionary

layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        if feature[idfield]-10 in d:
            new_value =  feature[oldlengthfield]/d[feature[idfield]-10]
        else:
            new_value = 999
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex(newlengthfield), new_value)
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

[image]

Comment: @Kazuhito do you know how to prevent it from printing True/False for each row in the python console?

Comment: I have to confess, I have achieved very little on python (though I vowed to learn it earlier this year ...) I am useless here. sorry :(

Comment: sorry I am a beginner in PyQGIS. For some reason I cant get those scripts to work :(. When running the code I get this error 
---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
KeyError: '-1'
---

Comment: @nico Have you changed the field names in the code to: `idfield = 'id'`, `oldlengthfield = 'length'` and `newlengthfield = 'length'`? You also need to have the layer added to table of contents and active (I think by clicking it once). Is you length field numeric type, not text/string?

Comment: @BERA The script works only if i want to recalculate the "length" field (oldlengthfield = newlengthfield). As in your example, I would like to have a new column with the results (newLength in your case". Layer is added, active and length field is numeric type.

Comment: And you have created the new length field with data type real(?)(/float/double/decimal)? The code will not create the new field.

Comment: It works!!!!!! I thought the script creates automatically the new field. Sorry for the inexperience. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

From your attribute table (as your posted image);

(1) start the **Field Calculator**

(2) `Create a new field` by naming a new `Output field name` (e.g. `divided`).

(3) Select `Decimal number` for the output field type.

(4) Enter expression as below and click on <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

**QGIS 3**

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id('your_layer', "id"+10), 'length') / "length"
```

**QGIS 2**

```
attribute(get_feature('your_layer', 'id', attribute($currentfeature, 'id')+10), 'length') / "length"
```

Please change `'your_layer'` to your actual layer name.

Comment: That was easier!

Comment: sorry I am a beginner in PyQGIS. For some reason I cant get those scripts to work :(

Comment: @nico They are expressions for the Field Calculator.

Comment: what is the difference between " " and ' ' ?

Comment: @nico `" "` is for the field name available in your current layer. `' '` is a part of the syntax but specific to this function. Please also see added explanation how to use the Field Calculator.

Comment: thanks for the visual information, but i don't get any value in the rows (just NULL)

Comment: @nico Have you changed `your_layer` part to your layer name?

Comment: @Kazuhito yes.. i can send you the shapefile if you want to give it a try

Comment: @nico If you can share it with us it will be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82833/discussion-between-nico-and-kazuhito).